# JSF : com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException

Tags: jsf

Here is my managed bean class :

```
package JSFinwis;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="authentificationBean")
@RequestScoped
public class authentificationBean implements Serializable {

List<clientBean> clients = new ArrayList<clientBean>();

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public authentificationBean() {
    super();
    clients.add(new    clientBean("X","Y","Z","T","W",new Date("1995-31-03")));
}

public List<clientBean> getClients()
{
    return this.clients;
}
}
```

However, I am getting this error :

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Impossible d’instancier la classe «JSFinwis.authentificationBean».

How can I solve this ?

Comment: By reading the root cause of the exception in the stack trace (and changing the development locale to English, so you get English error messages which usually yield so much more helpful hits in search engines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

1. you have `super();` in your constructor. remove that. Your class doesn't extends anything.
2. Is `clientBean` managed ? If so you shouldn't instantiate it yourself.
3. you should switch to CDI managed beans
4. CamelCase your class names.
5. I don't think making a RequestScoped bean Serializable serves any purpose since it's used only once.

Comment: I got it ! my "clientBean" was managed, I shouldn't have instantiated it.

Problem solved, thank you !

Comment: @no problem, upvoting the accepted answer is always nice for nice internet points